# A problem in the proof of Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm aware of the proof .  We consider $f(x)$ as a polynomial and then continue with this assumption but how we can prove that $f(x)$ can be represented by a polynomial ? Maybe it can't be matched with any polynomial . Really , I'm in doubt about it . Forgive me if this seems silly .

**Proof** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is very clear.

Comment: The proof of a taylor series I remember is just repeated applications of the FTC... No assumptions that a function may be represented as a polynomial.

Comment: it's better to put the proof you are following in the question, there are various proofs with different conditions on $f$ about Taylor's theorem, for instance it's not entirely clear whether $f$ in your question is real or complex. Without this info you cannot expect a good answer

Comment: @user160738 Okay , Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't assume that $f(x)$ is a polynomial, according to Lagrange's Remainder Theorem:

$f(x) = \sum^n_0a^ix_i + \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$ , where $a_i = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

and then we are proving that this remainder converges to $0$, hence $f(x)$ equals to this power series.

Comment: Okay but in the first proof that I've sent , it is assumed to be polynomial .

Comment: @S.H.W. I think it is just poor phrasing. It is not assumed, it is more of a thinking process: if $f(x)$ can actually be represented as series what its coefficients have to look like? And the only option is $a_i = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

Comment: Okay and what's the condition for it to be represented as series ?

Comment: The condition is: If $f(z)$ is analytic (as a function of a complex variable) in the disk $|z| < r$, then for every $z$ in that disk the series converges to $f(z)$.

Comment: The condition is to prove that for $n \rightarrow \infty$ the series converges to $f$ in some interval $(-R, R)$ (which is equivalent to proving that this remainder converges to $0$).